# Packages installing to virtualenv when not activated python

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv installed at `~/bot/` (in the `venv` subfolder.)

I've noticed recently that installing packages with `pip install --user` or even `sudo pip install` installs to this virtualenv, even after restarting. Python does not appear to see the `~/bot/~` in `python -m site`:

```
$ python -m site
sys.path = [
    '/home/modelmat',
    '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
    '/home/modelmat/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyrings.alt-3.0-py3.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zgitignore-0.8.0-py3.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3-1.22-py3.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/SecretStorage-2.3.1-py3.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests-2.18.4-py3.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.7.0-py3.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pycparser-2.18-py3.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil-5.4.3-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/onedrivesdk-1.1.8-py3.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keyring-11.0.0-py3.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/inotify_simple-1.1.7-py3.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/idna-2.6-py3.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography-2.1.4-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/colorama-0.3.9-py3.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click-6.7-py3.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cffi-1.11.5-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/certifi-2018.1.18-py3.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bidict-0.13.1-py3.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/onedriveClient-2.0.1-py3.7.egg',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six-1.11.0-py3.7.egg',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/modelmat/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/modelmat/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Yet, this is what packages show:

```
$ pip show websocket-client
Name: websocket-client
Version: 0.54.0
Summary: WebSocket client for Python. hybi13 is supported.
Home-page: https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client.git
Author: liris
Author-email: liris.pp@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: /home/modelmat/NormoBot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: six
Required-by:
```

Reinstalling:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall websocket-client
Uninstalling websocket-client-0.54.0:
  Would remove:
    /home/modelmat/bot/venv/bin/wsdump.py
    /home/modelmat/bot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket/*
    /home/modelmat/bot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket_client-0.54.0.dist-info/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled websocket-client-0.54.0
$ sudo pip install websocket-client
Collecting websocket-client
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/2d/f749a5c82f6192d77ed061a38e02001afcba55fe8477336d26a950ab17ce/websocket_client-0.54.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./bot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from websocket-client) (1.11.0)
Installing collected packages: websocket-client
Successfully installed websocket-client-0.54.0
```

This shows the same as the previous `pip show`. The exact same thing happens with `pip install --user`.

I'm really unsure how to fix this, everything appears to be installed inside of my virtualenv.

Comment: Did you activate the virtual environment? `source ~/bot/venv/bin/activate`

Comment: No, this issue is that it's installing to it without being activated. I don't want it to install there.

Comment: By chance do you have multiple pip versions? Where is `pip --version` pointing?

Comment: `pip --version`: pip 19.0.1 from /home/modelmat/bot/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
`which pip`: /home/modelmat/.local/bin/pip
(It's Arch Linux, so Python3.7 is the default).

Comment: From that, you can tell you are using venv's pip and not your system's pip. Figure out where is pip getting aliased. Or check your paths

Comment: Oh, it appears that there were pips from the virtualenv stored in ~/.local/bin, and removing then fixed the problem. But why would this occur?